# how to make german web site

Tags: encoding, utf-8, doctype, collation

what type of encoding or what do I have to do to make my web site display properly the text with German characters like this: Käse and not like this: K�se ?

Here is what I use for doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

and here is what I use for encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

the collation in mysql that I use is utf8_general_ci, I have never done web sites with other languages except for english (from scratch). I dont know what I am missing!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Instead of leaving an answer, please upvote and accept the answer that helped you the most.  (Click the green check mark next to the answer you want to accept.)  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Your encoding choise looks fine.

There is just two steps left: You have to make sure that the content type in the HTTP header also says the same, and you have to make sure that what you actually send *is* encoded using UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 should used for sites that cater for many languages, so is suitable for your needs.

The meta tag is correct too, though you may want to ensure that the server is sending the right `Content-Type` [header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Ensure that the HTML file is also encoded with UTF-8 and not ASCII or another codepage.

---

In general, you need to ensure that all steps from the DB to the browser use UTF-8 (so, DB columns are UTF-8, transferred to the server as UTF-8, rendered as UTF-8, transferred to the browser as UTF-8 with the right headers and meta tags).

Comment: @TooCooL - What web server are you using? To see the header, you can use firebug or the developer tools for your browser. As for the file encoding - a good text editor will allow you to save in UTF-8.

Comment: I am not testing it on web server but localy with xampp, and I dont know how to view it with firebug, by the way for some reason firebug has stoped to show me the default values that firefox adds in CSS

Answer (score 1):

From my expiriense, for utf-8 to work right:

1. MySql data needs to be in some of the "utf-8" collations
2. The meta tag needs to define charset as "utf-8"
3. The MySql connector needs to be set to "utf-8" (for php, its [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php))
4. The server-side file (*.php or the like) needs to be saved in utf-8 (not actually necesary, but it saves some pain)